# javascript is not working with doctype

Tags: javascript, html, doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
 <img src="nove.png" alt="" width="352" height="277" id="imageResize"  />
<div id="result"></div>
<script>


o = document.getElementById("imageResize");

o.style.padding = 500;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=o.style.width;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is simple web page. Try it on your pc with and without `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Why is it diffrent? Why javascript is not working with `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Comment: Please define "not working".  Does the js not execute at all, are there errors on the console, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS padding property takes a *length* not an integer.

```
500 + 'px'
```

Without the Doctype the browser enters [Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) and emulates ancient, buggy browsers which don't enforce that part of the spec.

Answer (score -1):

It's most likely browser's behavior

First, it's working, try to alert something out and it works

I don't know why the rest of the code does not work in HTML5 doctype but when u remove the doctype, maybe the browser try to make up for the html5 doctype with something else that actually works with the js code